# Manipulating row data with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a specific question, I have a link in a table in the third column of each row, when the user clicks that link he loads some ajax and updates the page, what I want to also happen is that in the 2nd column of the row where the link is, change the td's class from false to true, and the value from No to Yes.

Thanks!

**Update!
Code Example:**

The 2nd column still doesn't get updated on click, perhaps this is because the div where the table is located gets hidden onclick? Anyways here's what I've tried:

```
<tr>
  <td>00839</td>
  <td class="false"  style="text-align:left;">No</td>
  <td>      
    <a href="#" 
       onclick="Element.hide('ajax-instruction-view');; 
       new Ajax.Updater('ajax-instruction-view', '/tasks/show_ajax/839', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request){new Effect.Appear(&quot;ajax-instruction-view&quot;,{});window.scrollTo(0,0);
       link = $(link);
       var row = link.up('tr');
       var cell = row.down('td').next('td');
       cell.update('Yes');},
       parameters: 'authenticity_token='encodeURIComponent('SYWsdBTWlz17u9HmPXA2R9WmBfZn67g/IAMGyhHEwXw=')}); return false;"
    >
      Instructions-Notice Board
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>19/04/10</td>
  <td class="false">21/04/10</td>
  <td class="false"  style="text-align:left;">None.</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you using a framework or only raw javascript?

Comment: "change the td's class from false to true, and the value from No to Yes". Can you explain more on this?

Comment: Using Rails with the default javascript libraries, Prototype/Scriptaculous

My links are created with link_to_remote, but I can use raw javascript as well as I have mixed it in with the visual_effect helpers

Comment: @rahul 

<tr>
  <td>001</td>
  <td class="false">No</td>
  <td><a onclick="Element.hide('currentdiv');; new Ajax.Updater('someajax', 'ajax.html', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request){new Effect.Appear("newdiv",{});window.scrollTo(0,0);}, parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('SYWsdBTWlz17u9HmPXA2R9WmBfZn67g/IAMGyhHEwXw=')}); return false;">THE LINK</a>
</tr>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds as though at some point, you have a reference to the link the user clicked (either because you have a `click` handler on it or because you're using event delegation and finding it after a click on the table). Starting with a reference to that link, you can use Prototype's DOM traversal stuff to find the second table cell:

**Edit** Based on your response to rahul, I would change your link `onclick` to:

```
onclick="handleLinkClick(this); return false;"
```

...and this would be `handleLinkClick`:

```
function handleLinkClick(link) {

    // Original code (mostly unchanged)
    Element.hide('currentdiv');
    new Ajax.Updater('someajax', 'ajax.html', {
        asynchronous:true,
        evalScripts:true,
        onComplete: function(request) {
            new Effect.Appear("newdiv",{});
            window.scrollTo(0,0);

            // New code starts here

            // Extend the link element
            link = $(link);

            // Find the row
            var row = link.up('tr');

            // Find the second column
            var cell = row.down('td').next('td');

            // Change the cell's "class" and "value" -- I've had to guess a bit at
            // what you want to do here
            if (cell.hasClassName("true")) {
                cell.removeClassName("true").addClassName("false");
                cell.update("No");
            }
            else {
                cell.removeClassName("false").addClassName("true");
                cell.update("Yes");
            }

            // End of new code
        },
        parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('SYWsdBTWlz17u9HmPXA2R9WmBfZn67g/IAMGyhHEwXw=')
    });

}
```

That uses `Element#up`, `Element#next`, `Element#hasClassName`, `Element#addClassName`, `Element#removeClassName`, and `Element#update`; docs for them [here](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/).

Optional things to consider:

- The above is fragile in that if you change the location of that cell (make it the third column rather than the second), it fails. You might use a marker class to find it.
- Rather than an `onclick` attribute, you could use `Element#observe`.
- You can use event delegation to have just one handler on the table, rather than a handler on each link.

But the above should work.

Comment: Thank you for your extremely well written answer!

Comment: I need a little more assistance if possible, I don't think the code your gave me can is working correctly, I included a more detailed sample of my HTML to see if that helps.

Comment: @fivetwentysix: See my answer above, you want to move all of that code out of the `onclick` attribute and into a `script` section. Your code now quoted in your answer is missing a crucial bit where we pass `this` into the `handleLinkClick` function; this is how we know which link was clicked. You can do it with inline code (put `var link = this;` at the *very beginning* of the code in the attribute), but separating things out into a `script` section will make it a lot easier to read, maintain, and debug.

Answer (score 0):

I dont recall how to write it in Scriptaculous but in jQuery it would be:

```
$(element).click(function(){
  // invoke your ajax routine

  // change class
  $($(this).parent('tr').children().get(1)).attr('class', 'my-classname');
});
```

Maybe someone can translate :-)